# How to set many extensions in the same tab in Magento 2 admin panel?

Tags: magento2, module, admin

I'd like to create many extensions using the same tab like this sample on the image below, what I need to do in each extension to keep at the same tab?

**Stores > Settings > Configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael,
Pretty straight forward just use a consistent `<tab></tab>` in the system configuration between the extensions. For example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>

        <tab id="company" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>My Company Name</label>
        </tab>

       ... here you enter sections and fields etc ...


    </system>
</config>
```

As asked the ACL would be something as follows, please note that the Tab is not actually referenced.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Company_Modulename::system_config"
title="Some Great Name" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Magento by default won't show the tab if the user has no privileges to modules under it.

Comment: I guess that there is some ACL configuration that I need to do.

Comment: Shouldn't have to. The ACL applies to the sections not the tabs.

Comment: The tab is just tab, I'll update with an acl shortly.

Answer (score 1):

In the `system.xml` file of your extension you can put a section (free gift in your example) under any tab just by adding a child node to the `<section>` node called `<tab>` and the value of it should be an id of an existing tab.

Here is an example from the core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L16  and the tab declaration: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L10

Comment: I guess that there is some ACL configuration that I need to do.

Comment: How do you put a custom extensions setting pane under the General tab?

Comment: `<tab>general</tab>`